# Why changing one element of a vector will change all variables?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

Today I encountered this strange behavior in Python doing data manipulation. Why changing a will affect b below:

```
>>> a = ['Hello', 1, 2]
>>> b = a
>>> a[0] = 5
>>> b
[5, 1, 2]
```

I only asked a to change, why is b changing? But the following is fine,

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> a
3
>>> b
4
```

My guess is that I am doing passing by reference(?). But in both cases are passing by reference, what is going on here?

Comment: Mutable vs immutable variables. [Ints are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case, `list` what you're doing is copying a list, which is referencing a list to another list (ex: list `b` is referenced by list `a`).

In order to avoid that, you have to consider `deepcopy` in python in order to safely make edits to the copied list without those changes being reflected in the original.

For example,

```
 import copy
 a = ['Hello', 1, 2]
 b = copy.deepcopy(a)

 a[0] = 5
 print(b)  # This will give the original list
 >> ['Hello', 1, 2]
```

This is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) that will be helpful.

Another way to get around as @Sophie mentioned in the comment is slicing,

```
b= a[:]

a[0] = 5

print(a)
>> [5, 1, 2]

print(b)
>> ['Hello', 1, 2]
```

In your second case, it is just a reference to a variable as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Additionally, slicing copies sequences `b = a[:]` ([from python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python))

Comment: @SophieSearcy yes, slicing is another way around. I'll edit my answer with slicing too.

Comment: Thanks, how do I know if I am making a shallow copy or deep copy when using equal sign? There are list, dictionary, etc. The documentation is very technical to read.

Comment: As noted in the documentation `deepcopy` applies to `list` and `dictionaries`. If you are still want to know why? check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy

Comment: Great, very helpful! Why would one ever want to create a shallow copy? It's like calling the same person by two names. When we make a copy, we want to edit the copy WITHOUT touching the original. Isn't copy.copy() what we want by default when we type equal sign?

Comment: yes, you're right, sometimes we need something that preserve the old list or dictionary to perform data manipulation. I think this post's first answers especially by @cryo  has what I have to say showing examples with timing `copy.copy` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list